How to find the TPU forwards port of a validator node?
How do I determine the TPU forwarding port of a validator? Is there like a predetermined offset for this? Thanks!

When you call the GetClusterNodes method on a json rpc node you get an array of other node contact info like that :
{
"featureSet": null,
"gossip": "103.219.171.151:8000",
"pubkey": "86UUkVv9sQ1YYr2JBcF3wdPkPQ7nyfKhZc16vW2LkByD",
"pubsub": null,
"rpc": null,
"serveRepair": "103.219.171.151:8008",
"shredVersion": 50093,
"tpu": "103.219.171.151:8003",
"tpuForwards": "103.219.171.151:8004",
"tpuForwardsQuic": "103.219.171.151:8010",
"tpuQuic": "103.219.171.151:8009",
  "tpuVote": "103.219.171.151:8005",
  "tvu": "103.219.171.151:8001",
  "version": null
},

You still need to filter out the validator you want info from.
